# regex tweaking advice needed

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex which some kind folks on SO helped me with yesterday. Anyway I have been editing it to do another match now and have almost got it. Basically in the following text I need it to match the space before the year and to append a pipe `|` to that match. I can get it to match but it includes the first digit of the year, what should I do to only match the space. By the way the year may not just be a four digit sequence it may also be  `2206 & 2007` or `2004-2008` and so on.

```
105| Ryan, T.N. 2005. |

$(?:[^|]+\|){1}(.*?)\.\s\d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, you want to add a `|` between `Ryan, T.N.`and  `2005.`.

try this regex

```
^((?:[^|]+\|){1}.*?\.\s)(?=\d)
```

and replace with `$1` and `|`

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uqgo)

The `(?=\d)` is positive lookahead, it ensures, that there is a digit ahead without matching it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if I understand you correctly.

```
$string = preg_replace("#(.*) ([0-9]+.)#", "$1 | $2", "105| Ryan, T.N. 2005. |");
```